# 2 instances of a module pattern using a constructor function as the return value of the module

Tags: javascript, constructor, module, instance

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hb2pE/

I have a **constructor** function inside a **module pattern**. I create 2 instances of this module using this code:

```
var jo = new sliderJS("mySliderJS")
jo.start()


var jow = new sliderJS("mySliderJS2")
jow.start()
```

This is the module sliderJS:

```
var sliderJS = function($){

    var sliderJS, 
        sliderJSslide, 
        sliderJSslideLength, 
        sliderJSprev, 
        sliderJSnext,
        slideEvents,
        sliderID

    slideEvents = {

        doSlide: function(type, e){

            if(e){e.preventDefault()}

            for(var i = 0; i < sliderJSslideLength; i++){

                var slideIsActive = hasClass("active", sliderJSslide[i])

               if(slideIsActive){

                    sliderJSslide[i].className = "sliderJS-slide"

                   switch (type) {

                        case "next":

                            slideEvents.moveSlideNext(i)

                        break;

                        case "prev":

                            slideEvents.moveSlidePrev(i)

                        break;

                    }

                    break;

                }

            }

        },

        moveSlideNext: function(i){

            if(i+1 < sliderJSslide.length){

                sliderJSslide[i+1].className = "sliderJS-slide active"

            } else {

                sliderJSslide[0].className = "sliderJS-slide active"

            }

        },

        moveSlidePrev: function(i){

            if(i-1 != -1){

                sliderJSslide[i-1].className = "sliderJS-slide active"

            } else {

                sliderJSslide[sliderJSslide.length -1].className = "sliderJS-slide active"

            }

        }

    }


    function start(id){

        setVariables(id)
        setEventListeners()

    }

    function setVariables(id){

        //sliderID = id

        sliderJS = $("#" + sliderID)[0]

        sliderJSslide = $("#" + sliderID + " > .sliderJS-slide")
        sliderJSslideLength = sliderJSslide.length

        sliderJSprev = $("#" + sliderID + "-prev")[0]
        sliderJSnext = $("#" + sliderID + "-next")[0]

    }

    function setEventListeners(){

        sliderJSnext.addEventListener("click", function(){return function(e){ slideEvents.doSlide("next", e)}}())
        sliderJSprev.addEventListener("click", function(){return function(e){ slideEvents.doSlide("prev", e)}}())

    }

    function hasClass(parClass, parElement){

        if(parElement.className.indexOf(parClass) == -1){return false} else {return true}

    }


    return function constr(id){

        sliderID = id
        this.start = start


    }

}(Sizzle)
```

If i'm using only 1 instance than the code works. As soon as i create a second instance the slider for the first one stops working because all the variables values have been changed to reflect the second slider.

What am i doing wrong?

Here is that jsFiddle again (remove the last instance -var jow- to see the script actually working): http://jsfiddle.net/hb2pE/

Comment: Are you meaning to call `constr` from somewhere?

Comment: No, constr is just the returning function so that i can use the new keyword to get a new object. So constr is the constructor function.

Comment: the `new` keyword and the module pattern aren't really compatible concepts. Edit: I see what you mean, although creating a new instance of your constr function won't result in a new instance of anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module is a little bit messed up. It should follow this pattern:

```
var sliderJS = function(sliderID) {

    //define private functions here eg. setEventListeners

    //Return an object containing functions that are public eg. doSlide
    return {
        doSlide: function(type, e){

        }
    };
};
```

So you don't need the new keyword, just call:

```
var slider1 = sliderJS("mySliderJS2");
```

If, however, you're creating a lot of instances and would prefer better performance, you'd be better off creating a function and populating its prototype - then you can call that function with the `new` keyword.

Comment: Thx, for you answer... i removed the constructor function and am now using a revealing module pattern instead. So to start the slider i now use: var jo = sliderJS; jo.start("mySliderJS"). However, again, if want to use another slider on the same page, a click on 'next' or 'prev' iterates trough the slides of the second object, check this fiddle to see what i mean: http://jsfiddle.net/hb2pE/4/

Comment: I looked at the fiddle - get rid of the `$` arg on your function and the `(jQuery)` call. Add brackets to execute sliderJS, ie. `var jo = sliderJS();`. (If you want to ensure $ is mapped to jQuery, it would be easier to do it in an outer-most scope)

Comment: Johnny, could you update my jsFiddle with a working example, that would be great thx..

Comment: euh, ... thx but there seems to be something wrong, both 'prev + next' links are still sliding the last slider.

Comment: Great thx... i understand now. I'm still getting confused about the values everything has at the time it gets defined or called.... That's the big problem i'm having with javascript at the moment. Very frustrating...

Comment: Here's a great article by @ColinE that will help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687093/Understanding-JavaScript-Object-Creation-Patterns